# drop-down list with search capability

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

Suppose I have simple drop-down list - `(http://jsfiddle.net/J52s9/).` Here for this drop-down list How i can have a search option.

For example if in the textbox user writes **Weeks** the drop-down list having week as a part of string should only appear .

I am using php.

I tired-

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="dateRange" id="mySelect" size="1">
           <option value > Select Duration </option>
           <option value="A">Last 24 Hours</option>
           <option value="B">Last 2 Days</option>
           <option value="C">Last Week</option>
           <option value="D">Last 2 Weeks</option>
           <option value="E">Last Month</option>
           <option value="F">Last 3 Months</option>
           <option value="G">Last 6 Months</option>
           <option value="H">Last Year</option>
    </select> 
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').chosen();
    });

Please guide.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

[chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is a nice [jQuery](http://jquery.com) plugin for that

```
$('select').chosen();
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J52s9/2/

Comment: can you pls check the update question. I posted wht i tired after your answer but thats not working for me

Comment: also include jquery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js and chosen.css file

Comment: "code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" and

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/chosen/chosen.css">

Comment: i have included both but still its not working for me

Comment: ok, include jquery first, then chosen.js - also add `http://` in front of `code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`

Comment: it is working but only when I press "L". search is not same as of the fiddle that u posted

Comment: pls send me the link to your site

Comment: dont have access to your localhost, possible to upload your site ?

Comment: hm so i cant help you from now on, take a look at working jsfiddle example, also check your code for syntax errors and other mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 datalist element to do as per your requirement.
Check if this is what you need:

Copy the following in an html file.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label>Search</label>
    <input list='mySelect'>
    <datalist name="dateRange" id="mySelect" size="1">
           <option value > Select Duration </option>
           <option value="A">Last 24 Hours</option>
           <option value="B">Last 2 Days</option>
           <option value="C">Last Week</option>
           <option value="D">Last 2 Weeks</option>
           <option value="E">Last Month</option>
           <option value="F">Last 3 Months</option>
           <option value="G">Last 6 Months</option>
           <option value="H">Last Year</option>
    </datalist> 
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>`

Comment: but i don't my dropdown list to appear like this.